# Verbose `Dynamic` variable lists

Tags: function-construction, dynamic

Is there a way to achieve the following without listing all of the dynamic pieces so verbosely / manually listing all the dynamic variables?

```
pieces=Import["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons"<>#]&/@{"/c/cd/Chess_pdt60.png","/0/04/Chess_plt60.png",
"/f/f1/Chess_ndt60.png","/2/28/Chess_nlt60.png",
"/8/81/Chess_bdt60.png","/9/9b/Chess_blt60.png",
"/a/a0/Chess_rdt60.png","/5/5c/Chess_rlt60.png",
"/a/af/Chess_qdt60.png","/4/49/Chess_qlt60.png",
"/e/e3/Chess_kdt60.png","/3/3b/Chess_klt60.png"};

chess=DynamicModule[{
lk={5,1},
dk={5,8},
lq={4,1},
dq={4,8},
lr1={1,1},lr2={8,1},
dr1={1,8},dr2={8,8},
lb1={3,1},lb2={6,1},
db1={3,8},db2={6,8},
ln1={2,1},ln2={7,1},
dn1={2,8},dn2={7,8},

lp1={1,2},lp2={2,2},lp3={3,2},lp4={4,2},lp5={5,2},lp6={6,2},lp7={7,2},lp8={8,2},
dp1={1,7},dp2={2,7},dp3={3,7},dp4={4,7},dp5={5,7},dp6={6,7},dp7={7,7},dp8={8,7}

},Module[{dark,light},dark=Hue[{0.57,0.4,0.6}];
light=Nest[Lighter,dark,5];Deploy@Graphics[{Table[{FaceForm[None],EdgeForm[dark],Rectangle[{1,1}-.5,{9,9}-.5],FaceForm[If[OddQ[i+j],light,dark]],Rectangle[{i,j}-.5,{i+1,j+1}-.5]},{i,1,8,1},{j,1,8,1}],

Locator[Dynamic[lk,(lk=Round/@#)&],pieces[[12]]],
Locator[Dynamic[dk,(dk=Round/@#)&],pieces[[11]]],

Locator[Dynamic[lq,(lq=Round/@#)&],pieces[[10]]],
Locator[Dynamic[dq,(dq=Round/@#)&],pieces[[9]]],

Locator[Dynamic[lr1,(lr1=Round/@#)&],pieces[[8]]],
Locator[Dynamic[lr2,(lr2=Round/@#)&],pieces[[8]]],
Locator[Dynamic[dr1,(dr1=Round/@#)&],pieces[[7]]],
Locator[Dynamic[dr2,(dr2=Round/@#)&],pieces[[7]]],

Locator[Dynamic[lb1,(lb1=Round/@#)&],pieces[[6]]],
Locator[Dynamic[lb2,(lb2=Round/@#)&],pieces[[6]]],
Locator[Dynamic[db1,(db1=Round/@#)&],pieces[[5]]],
Locator[Dynamic[db2,(db2=Round/@#)&],pieces[[5]]],

Locator[Dynamic[ln1,(ln1=Round/@#)&],pieces[[4]]],
Locator[Dynamic[ln2,(ln2=Round/@#)&],pieces[[4]]],
Locator[Dynamic[dn1,(dn1=Round/@#)&],pieces[[3]]],
Locator[Dynamic[dn2,(dn2=Round/@#)&],pieces[[3]]],

Locator[Dynamic[lp1,(lp1=Round/@#)&],pieces[[2]]],
Locator[Dynamic[lp2,(lp2=Round/@#)&],pieces[[2]]],
Locator[Dynamic[lp3,(lp3=Round/@#)&],pieces[[2]]],
Locator[Dynamic[lp4,(lp4=Round/@#)&],pieces[[2]]],
Locator[Dynamic[lp5,(lp5=Round/@#)&],pieces[[2]]],
Locator[Dynamic[lp6,(lp6=Round/@#)&],pieces[[2]]],
Locator[Dynamic[lp7,(lp7=Round/@#)&],pieces[[2]]],
Locator[Dynamic[lp8,(lp8=Round/@#)&],pieces[[2]]],

Locator[Dynamic[dp1,(dp1=Round/@#)&],pieces[[1]]],
Locator[Dynamic[dp2,(dp2=Round/@#)&],pieces[[1]]],
Locator[Dynamic[dp3,(dp3=Round/@#)&],pieces[[1]]],
Locator[Dynamic[dp4,(dp4=Round/@#)&],pieces[[1]]],
Locator[Dynamic[dp5,(dp5=Round/@#)&],pieces[[1]]],
Locator[Dynamic[dp6,(dp6=Round/@#)&],pieces[[1]]],
Locator[Dynamic[dp7,(dp7=Round/@#)&],pieces[[1]]],
Locator[Dynamic[dp8,(dp8=Round/@#)&],pieces[[1]]]
},
Frame->False]]
];
chess
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But instead of having all those different dynamic variables, create only one and let it be a *list* of all your pieces, ``DynamicModule[{p = {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, ...}}, ...]``. Then, use ``Table`` like: ``Table[With[{i = i}, Locator[Dynamic[p[[i]], (p[[i]] = Round /@ #) &], pieces[[i]]]], {i, 32}]``

Comment: @Domen many thanks - worked great. Delete question do you think?

Comment: Well, perhaps one of the more experienced users might come up with an actual solution of how to generate dynamic variables from a list (there is probably some hackery with scoping).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Domen's comment:

```
chessfen@"2r3k1/pb4p1/4p3/1p3p1q/5Pn1/P1NQb2P/1P4P1/R1B2R1K w - - 4 24"
```

with

```
chessfen[fen_,size_]:=DynamicModule[{poslist,pieces,piecesAll},poslist=Select[Thread[{DeleteCases[Characters[StringReplace[StringExtract[fen,1],n_/;DigitQ[n]:>StringJoin@ConstantArray[" ",ToExpression[n]]]],"/"],Flatten[Reverse[Table[{j,i},{i,8},{j,8}]],1]}],#[[1]]!=" "&];
pieces=Import["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons"<>#]&/@{"/c/cd/Chess_pdt60.png","/0/04/Chess_plt60.png","/f/f1/Chess_ndt60.png","/2/28/Chess_nlt60.png","/8/81/Chess_bdt60.png","/9/9b/Chess_blt60.png","/a/a0/Chess_rdt60.png","/5/5c/Chess_rlt60.png","/a/af/Chess_qdt60.png","/4/49/Chess_qlt60.png","/e/e3/Chess_kdt60.png","/3/3b/Chess_klt60.png"};
piecesAll=poslist[[All,1]]/.Thread[Characters["rnbqkpRNBQKP"]->Part[pieces,{8,4,6,10,12,2,7,3,5,9,11,1}]];
DynamicModule[{p=poslist[[All,2]]},Module[{dark,light},dark=Hue[{0.57,0.4,0.6}];
light=Nest[Lighter,dark,5];Deploy[Graphics[{Table[{FaceForm[None],EdgeForm[dark],Rectangle[{1,1}-.5,{9,9}-.5],FaceForm[If[OddQ[i+j],light,dark]],Rectangle[{i,j}-.5,{i+1,j+1}-.5]},{i,1,8,1},{j,1,8,1}],Table[With[{i=i},Locator[Dynamic[p[[i]],(p[[i]]=Round/@#)&],ImageResize[#,Floor[size/6.5]]&@piecesAll[[i]]]],{i,Length@poslist}]},Frame->False,ImageSize->size]]]]];
chessfen[fen_]:=chessfen[fen,380];
```

[image]

Also seems to work fine inside `Manipulate`:

```
(*https://www.chess-poster.com/english/lt_pgn_to_fen/lt_pgn_fen.htm*)
anand13=chessfen/@StringSplit[#,"\n"]&@Uncompress["1:eJyd1sGOqjAUBuB5gHmIzgMY/c8pjJO7Y2tCqnd7V703szFhwA2vfyu0ULG0RY3Gzf/l72kRPvTP5fev97e3W6O7q25u+9a+9kfzZiXNt1IK5qP2l7o6n6r6IrQ4na+d+MfiIPDnAPLjsHFu5SrQW6A0AMUAUlagYIO/HABoyFNbRAVbYWcATgNFTQsCU4mdgE/AJ6ihBDL1ICFzEKrJZ7Dswk8MjwraDMabSpHHQA0Oh9s4BhODBhugfh5xmQtVS4i8QpRwjubHquJN5zOlVOFF0cNwFgo9IGjLGGPL6Ps1dEw5nJ4MPIV8RKcR7xB/vYTgcoKpYk/wZOB2xUakN8JOSIHDJuRMVqGxyR0pHELW0NiCjE1KAeQgCqOCYJWDVej2mjJ2gQDFFVljdnilDK0xbJWW40zv1sQBpp6ZIt0lhrAzzN7Hq5jByKQC9cDwosv3cDeMMmaP2ogyjaVIIHMVGWoSMeRA6CJqTDMpc43iTqBC6KgsEPYINBxHxiYs8JlGqhkJDmSdoLugV4VpW44vCTjZDogJ5ZBvwvmpwZfL1y6PnLxeycspzi2lCnwPD2sHK5AHwFztScLNwAnsAV0O0NsDRcgDpBoFPI0hJKDLEdxGEG0Q6IynEggS406giwvTIDhLMAswhHyqwHGgcHFNy7y7xdLwZ/cfcQVLLA=="];
Manipulate[anand13[[a]],
{{a,1},1,46,1,Appearance->{"Open"}}]
```